# Strange Behavior of Compile[] inside With[]

Tags: functions, function-construction, programming, compile, scoping

Consider, in the examples below, the difference between defining $n$ as a global variable or as an argument to function `comp[]`, which includes a compiled function that depends on a constant defined in an encompassing `With[]` which depends on $n$.

1. If I evaluate

```
ClearAll[comp, n]

n = 3;

comp = With[{x = n^2},
   Compile[{}, x]];
```

then running `comp[]` outputs 9. This is fine.

2. If I evaluate

```
ClearAll[comp, n]

comp = With[{x = n^2},
   Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, x]];
```

then running `comp[3]` outputs 9. This is fine.

3. If I evaluate

```
ClearAll[comp, n]

n = 3;

comp = With[{x = Array[#^2 &, n]},
   Compile[{}, x]];
```

then running `comp[]` gives me `{1,4,9}`. This is fine.

4. However, if I evaluate

```
ClearAll[comp, n]

comp = With[{x = Array[#^2 &, n]},
   Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, x]];
```

I get the error *"Array: Single or list of non-negative machine-sized integers expected at position 2 of Array[#1^2&,n]"*. The output to `comp[3]` is still `{1,4,9}` (however, in more complicated forms of example 4, the output is not what it should be).

Example 1 is to example 3 as example 2 is to example 4.

***Why do examples 1-3 not give an error but example 4 does?***

Answer (score 4):

The error is thrown by `Array`, not by compile. `With` has to evaluate the code for `x` first and this is why `Array` throws the error.

Comment: `Compile[]` is an important part though, is it not? For example, no error is thrown in either `f[n_] := With[{x = Array[#^2 &, n]}, 2]` or `f = With[{x = Array[#^2 &, n]}, Function[n, 2]]` (`f[3]`, for example, throws no error). If you mean the error is "Array:..." then I agree; I mentioned this in my question.

Comment: `f = With[{x = Array[#^2 &, n]}, Function[n, 2]]` _does_ throw the same error if `n` is undefined.

Comment: My bad, thank you. I forgot to clear n.

Comment: What would be the best way to pass `n` as an argument to `comp` without throwing the error? (Essentially, I'd like to get the behavior of example 3 but define `n` as an argument, to `comp`, not as a global variable). I know I can do something like `comp[n_] := With[{x = Array[#^2 &, n]}, f = Compile[{}, x]; f[]]`, and `comp[3]` gives me the right answer with no error, but introducing `f` is a bit sloppy. Do you believe this is best?

Comment: Well, this error can easily be ignored. You can do `comp = Quiet[With[{x = Array[#^2 &, n]},
   Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, x]]];`. But an easier way would be `comp = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Array[#^2 &, n]]`. Or `comp = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Table[i^2 &, {i, 1, n}]]`.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to keep `With[]` and the constants it defines. My issue is the function I am using is more complicated – it needs the constants (actually bodies of pure functions) define by `With[]` as is or suffers significant performance issues. Moreover, the error is lethal for my particular function. Essentially, what I did in example 3 works for my function, but I'd like to bring `n` in as an argument. What I did in example 4 is disastrous for my function.

Answer (score 4):

As explained by Henrik, the problem is that `Array` is being evaluated before it gets inserted into `Compile`.  The solution here is to use `SetDelayed` to prevent its evaluation.

```
comp = With[{x := Array[#^2 &, n]}, Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, x]]
```

Comment: This seems to work, but the function I am using suffered a massive drop in speed, probably because x is now being evaluated millions of times.

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
comp = With[{x = Unevaluated@Array[#^2 &, n]}, 
  Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, x]]
```

By the way, `Trace` or `TracePrint` will show the order of evaluation, when there is a question about what is happening.  When the code is short, like in this case, it can clarify what is going on.

```
TracePrint@With[{x = Array[#^2 &, n]}, Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, x]]
```

It also shows the desired code is injected for `x`, despite the error.

Comment: I use a variation of this technique: I let `body = Hold[Unevaluated[Array[#^2 &, n]]];` so that I can readily generate compiled and uncompiled versions of the same code: `fCompiled = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, #] & @@ body` and `fUncompiled = Function[{n}, #] & @@ body`.